# Redirect URI error when signing into google with react-native expo

Tags: react-native, expo, google-signin

using expo auth session to authenticate with google have all my android & ios apps set up accordingly but this redirect uri issue has me stumped. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Image of error message]

```
import React, { createContext, useContext } from 'react';
import * as Google from 'expo-auth-session/providers/google';

const AuthContext = createContext({});

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {

  const config = {
    androidClientId: "redacted",
    iosClientId: "redacted",
  };
  const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest(config);

  const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
    try {
      await promptAsync(); // Wait for the authentication prompt

      // Additional logic after authentication
      // For example, you can fetch user data here

    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error during Google sign-in:", error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider 
        value={{
            user: null,
            signInWithGoogle: signInWithGoogle,
        }}
    >
        {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default function useAuth() {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}
```

have tried explicitly adding a redirectUri to the config like so:

```
const config = {
    androidClientId: "redacted",
    iosClientId: "redacted",
    redirectUri: "redacted",
  };
```

tried using the ios bundleId/android package name as the redirectUri but no luck

Comment: Adding a valid redirect uri fixed this

Comment: what would be the valid redirect uri? The app scheme? for example: com.something.example?